# SQLAlchemy : can't make event.listens.for() work

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am new to SQLAlchemy and jumped into it for its ease of use and event mechanisms. I am looking to execute a method after some data is inserted but I keep running into several errors of the type "Attribute[...]" related to the object I am referring to

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Integer, UnicodeText
from sqlalchemy import event

#variables feching is hidden
db = create_engine("mysql://"+dbLogin+":"+dbPassword+"@"+dbAddress+"/"+dbDatabase)
metadata = MetaData(db)
#the log table is not explicitly defined but rather uses the autoload function
logtable = Table('logs', metadata, autoload=True)

#and here I am trying to start "processLogChanged" after_insert on the "logs" table
@event.listens_for(logtable, "after_insert")
def processLogChanged():
    print "---- the log table has changed"
```

I am obviously doing something wrong but I have been scouring through a lot of questions/answers and can't find the right here, it would be great if you could give me a hand

Here is the stack for instance in that case

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "optra.py", line 144, in <module>@event.listens_for(logtable, "after_insert")
    File "/home/jpp/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/api.py", line 124, in decorate
    listen(target, identifier, fn, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/jpp/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/api.py", line 89, in listen
    _event_key(target, identifier, fn).listen(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/jpp/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/registry.py", line 194, in listen
    dispatch_collection = getattr(target.dispatch, identifier)
  File "/home/jpp/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/base.py", line 95, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: after_insert
```

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

`after_insert` event assumes you are using tables declared by `sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base`. And you need to specify `mapper`, `connection`, `target` arguments for event handler:

```
Base = declarative_base(metadata)

class LogTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'logs'

    id = Column(Integer)
    # Some other columns

@event.listens_for(LogTable, 'after_insert')
def processLogChanged(mapper, connection, target):
    print "---- the log table has changed"
```